# Multiple copy constructors specified

Tags: templates, visual-c++, constructor, c++11, gcc4

With Visual C++ 2010, I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(){}
    MyClass(MyClass &){/*...*/}   //A
    MyClass(const MyClass &){/*...*/}   //B
    template<typename T> MyClass(T &&t){ static_assert(
        !std::is_same<typename 
        std::remove_cv<typename  std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type, 
        MyClass>::value,
        "Wrapping over wrapping is not allowed!"); } //C
};

int main(int, char**){
    MyClass a;
    const MyClass b(a); //assert fail if line A removed
    auto c=b; //assert fail if line B removed
}
//If both A and B exists
//Warning C4521: multiple copy constructors specified
//Furthermore, if both A and B removed
//No error or warnings; VC2010 accepts peacefully.
//In debug mode you will find the compiler generated trivial copy constructor
```

According to C++ standard, both line A and B are considered copy constructors, and C is a convert constructor. It is not surprising that I receive a warning that I declared multiple copy constructors. However, if I remove any of them, the static_assert fails and the code would not compile, that means the template constructor received control.

I am sure that this behaviour follows the rule of function overloading. However is this a conflict of two rules? If A and B are copy constructors and one of them was declared, any attempt to copy the objects should not drop to the template, is it right?

Update:
According to N3242, 12.8.7,

> "a member function template is NEVER INSTANTIATED to perform the copy of a class object to an object of its class type."

the correct implementation should be:

- No assert failure should occur when either A or B or both removed.
- If line B is removed, construction of c should fail because b is const.
- If both lines are removed, compiler should generate a copy constructor for the class.
- It is up to the implementation to warn the user if both lines exists.

Any comment?

Comment: You've brought this on yourself with the inclusion of the `static_assert`.  I can think of no good reason to not allow conversion from type `T&` to type `const T&` - can you?

Comment: This is just a dummy implementation of my class. The template constructor should have different logic than the copy constructor.

Comment: To implement the template convert constructor, usually a contained storage should be used to store the value of t. If t is instance of MyClass, it would introduce wrapping over wrapping, which is what I am tring to prevent.

Comment: I understand why you ask now. The original code is misleading. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `template<T>` should be `template <typename T>`.

I am using gcc 4.4.3 on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux, the codes behave differently from what you have demonstrated in the post.

- If nothing changed, the codes could be compiled without any warning. The constructor A and B are evoked one after another.
- If I comment line A, it fails to be compiled just as what you said: failing in line `const MyClass b(a);`. The reason is that the object a is not constant, so constructor B can not be matched and the compiler has to instantiate the template constructor. Of course, `const MyClass` and `MyClass` are different types.
- However, if I comment line B only, the codes could be compiled successfully and the template copy constructor was evoked. Object b is a constant object, so construct A can not be matched and the compiler instantiate the template constructor. However, the question remains: should the static_assert fails or not? The difference may be because of the platform/compiler difference. GCC seems implementing the `is_same<MyClass&&, MyClass>::value` to be true. You may use typeid to print out both of the types.

Comment: obviously there are different implementations. If you remove both A and B in GCC, you will get a failed assert, but this is not happen in VC++. I refered the latest draft (N3242), it seems saying that a copy constructor is non-template(12.8.2). So at least in this case GCC seems to against it and allowed the template version to be copy constructor.

Comment: I should say that the standard said "a member function template is NEVER INSTANTIATED to perform the copy of a class object to an object of its class type"(12.8.7). According to this, I consider both GCC and VC2010 is failed to follow. GCC instantiated the template version if both A and B removed; and VC2010 instantiated the template version when one of them removed but not all.

Comment: for the class compare assert, the correct expression should be `!std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type, MyClass>::value`

Comment: I am going to mark this as the correct answer, just because it includes another case study for GCC.

Comment: Yes, when using std::is_same, always remember to remove reference and constant modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

> If A and B are copy constructors and one of them was declared, any attempt to copy the objects should not drop to the template, is it right?

A constructor that is not a copy constructor can still be used to copy objects. In your case the constructor instantiated from the constructor template is used for copying the object. Which is fine.

Comment: This involves another problem. If both lines A and B are removed, Visual Studio 2010 generates a trivial copy constructor and none of construction of object b and c drop to the template, i.e. the compiler accepts the code happily, which is not what I want as well.